# Как заполнить массив одним вводом?

Tags: c++

я столкнулся с проблемой как заполнить массив по циферно одним вводом данных без прерываний.
Это тоджно выглядеть так:
Человек вводит одним разом 53734
И в массив вводятся значения 5,3,7,3,4.
Ввод данных должен происходить без прерываний.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну пробелами-то их можно разделять? :) Или смысл в том, что в каждый элемент только одна цифра? Да, размер массива известен?

Comment: Размер массива не известен но код для его определения я уже сделал. Просто не понимаю именно как сделать так что бы его по циферно заполнить. Для примера можно оставить 5 значений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю ваши невысказанные пожелания, вам надо что-то [типа этого](https://ideone.com/VSbzBA)?

```
int arr[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    char c; cin >> c; arr[i] = c-'0';
}
```

Comment: Больше спасибо!